# How to only download unique pictures/media from subreddit

Tags: python-3.x, reddit, praw

I was trying to do a meme scraper script in python.

The script is quite simple for now. It simply searches a subreddit and download the media based on the filter.

Below is the script i wrote. I am using the praw library:

```
import praw
import requests

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")

for submission in subreddit.top(limit = 10):
    img_data = requests.get(submission.url).content
    filename = submission.url.split('/')
    with open(filename[-1], 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)
    print(submission.url)
```

The problem is that it may sometimes download the same media repeatedly. Therefore, I would like to configure it such that when it runs, it always returns 10 unique media for me. May I know if any reddit pros know how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

This is the code that I was suggested to use. Basically, it checks if a given id is already saved in the database. The id can be found via PRAW.

```
def save_id(submission_id):
    write_down_id_somewhere(...)

def is_known_id(submission_id):
    # check here to see if it's saved somewhere

for submission in subreddit.top(limit = 10):
    if is_known_id(submission.fullname):
        continue
    img_data = requests.get(submission.url).content
    filename = submission.url.split('/')
    with open(filename[-1], 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)
    save_id(submission.fullname)
    print(submission.url)
```